# How to refresh page after send_data in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Hello devs i'm generating a csv in my controllers but everytime the user clicks on download, it has to refresh manually, how can i avoid this?

```
        @archivo_csv = CSV.generate(:encoding => 'windows-1252') do |csv|
            csv  <<  ["indicator","count"]
            @indicator[1..@indicator.size].each_with_index do |indicator, i|
                csv << ["#{indicator[0]}", indicator[1]]
                    indicator[2].each do |date|
                        csv << ["    #{date[0]}", date[1]]
                    end
                    indicator[3].each do |status|
                        csv << ["    #{status[0]}", status[1]]
                    end
            end
send_data @archivo_csv, :filename => "Indicadores Generales.csv"
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve that is by using Javascript. Add `target="_blank"` and `onclick="JavaScript:location.reload(true);"` to the HTML form. I used button_to tag like this:

```
<%= button_to 'Download',
              download_entity_path(@entity, format: :pdf),
              method: :get,
              form: {target: :blank,
                     onclick: 'JavaScript:location.reload(true);'} 
%>
```

Be aware that the browser might treat the download as a pop-up.